# Chrome extension. Is it possible to open links in popup?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have a popup.html as follows

```
<html>
  <head>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href = "http://google.com"> Google </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open it and click the link nothing happens. Is it possible to follow the
links in the popup but not in the new tabs?

```
my manifest.json

{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Go link",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Go link",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*",  
 ]
}
```

Comment: So, you're wanting to follow the link within the popup (and specifically not in an existing or new tab)?